# How to transfer SQLite database from Eclipse to my Android Phone?

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I created a project on Eclipse with SQLite Database. It is a data entry system in which the user enters the login credentials and if the credentials match with the data stored in the database he is allowed to login and insert or update information. 
This is working perfectly fine with the Emulator device, but when I transferred the .apk file to my Android mobile, it throws an exception "No such table".
I want to know how the database which is present on Eclipse be transferred to my phone along with the apk file.
Thanks in advance.
PS: I am using DB Browser for SQLite to create tables.
[This is the exception that I am getting on my phone which is viewed on a Toast, 'master' is the table name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6g9J.png)

Comment: post some code, stacktrace of your exception

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of the exception. Kindly check.

Comment: show some code related to your activity where you are accessing database and your database classes where you create your tables

Comment: Just use [SQLiteAssetHelper](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-sqlite-asset-helper/) instead.